# Show selection set in Attributes Window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, vb.net

I have an ArcObjects extension that creates a selection set and then zooms to the selected features.  This part works as expected.  The problem that we are having, however, is that the selection set does not display in the Attributes Window as it would if you were to use the normal selection tools in ArcGIS.

I looked at the IAttributeWindow interface but it seems that this is more concerned with showing that window rather than populating it.

Does anyone know which interface I need to look at for this, or if anyone can point me to an example?

We're running ArcGIS 10.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to call ISelectionEvents.SelectionChanged() to update this window.  Put this after your selection is made, and it should work:

```
Dim pSelectionEvents As ISelectionEvents = My.ArcMap.Document.FocusMap
pSelectionEvents.SelectionChanged()
```